# Is it correct to use "in this case" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, semantics

I've been given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370300/3233388) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), in which answerer said:

> It's perfectly possible to call `func` from outside a labelled context, so `break` wouldn't refer to anything.

I asked OP if what was meant was "**but** `break` wouldn't refer to anything" but apparently OP did mean to use "so" in that sentence, as "in this case".

English is not my native language, so I might be wrong, but since "perfectly possible" was used, I didn't expect a "wouldn't refer to anything" ending. That wouldn't be perfect at all. Since OP meant "in this case", I expected to see a "but" instead of "so" (or "in this case").

Is it correct to use "in this case" in that sentence?

Comment: "So", in this context, means "as a result".

Comment: @HotLicks even if that wouldn't be perfect, so would contradict with "perfectly possible"?

Comment: In this context, 'so' is incorrect for 'and the problem is that, this being the case, [_break_ would have nothing to refer to].

Answer (score 0):

'so' and 'therefore' or 'thus' (bit more archaic) can be considered as synonyms. However, 'so' is usually employed in a more colloquial context. I would probably say 'so in this case' or 'therefore in this instance' rather than using 'so' on its own. Nevertheless, whilst I am not a native speaker of English, I do know that 'so' is used in spoken English to indicate 'in this case' when one refers to something which was spoken about and is therefore considered implicitly understood.

Comment: Hmm this answer made me realize I didn't word my question very well. Please check the edit